Which game is "that 651"?
In Act 1, scene 2, Troy and Rose have the following exchange:

Rose: That 651 hit yesterday. That's the second time this month. Miss Pearl hit for a dollar... seems like those that need the least always get lucky. Poor folks can't get nothing.
Troy: Them numbers don't know nobody. I don't know why you fool with them. You and Lyons both.

What, exactly, is "that 651" in this context? It's apparently some kind of numbers game, but I don't understand exactly what it is or how it works.

Fences is set in 1950s Pittsburgh, which was a notable location where the "numbers game" was played, a form of illegal betting that had first been developed among the black community in Harlem in the 1920s. An entry in the blog Steel City Vice ("The history of numbers gambling, bootlegging, and corruption in Pittsburgh") recounts:

[her] acceptance speech drew from memories of Pittsburgh’s once rich
numbers gambling culture. Numbers is an informal and illegal daily
street lottery that arrived in Pittsburgh in the 1920s... The game
relied on a three-digit number derived from daily financial market
returns published in daily newspapers. If bettors picked the correct
three-digit number, they could convert a nickel into $30 and a dime
into $60 — much more than the average pay for many Pittsburgh
residents.

The mechanics of the game were that a player would select a three digit number, and would bet a certain amount of money on those numbers "coming up". Runners would collect the money from the bettors each day, leave each bettor a receipt, and then take the money to the clearing house, also known as a policy bank. A player would win if his/her numbers matched a preset series of three numbers.
The numbers game was big business in Pittsburgh, and supported a whole infrastructure:

By the mid-1930s, numbers gambling had infiltrated all corners of the
city. There were numbers racketeers and corrupt politicians from city
hall to corner markets. If Pittsburghers weren’t running numbers, they
were betting on them.

The winning numbers were selected by some "random" mechanism, such as the final three digits of the NYSE closing price. It appears from the text that the sequence 651 had came up twice that month, and on one of those occasions Miss Pearl won the lottery. It is not completely clear whether "Miss Pearl hit for a dollar" means that Miss Pearl won a dollar, or whether she bet a dollar, but as Peter Shor points out in the comments, the second seems more feasible. If she had a spare dollar and bet it - an amount in line with the nickel and dime bets mentioned in the references - she would certainly fall into the class of people described in the question as "those that need the least", and would have pocketed a reasonably substantial pot of a few hundred dollars.

I can't believe that Miss Pearl only won a dollar. If the odds given by your sources are correct, she would have had to bet a sixth of a cent for this too happen.  I suspect this means that she bet a dollar and won $600.

@PeterShorYou may be right. But you also have to account for the overhead deducted by the gangsters who ran the racket.

This is probably introducing more math than is warranted into a discussion of literature. But if you're betting on 3-digit numbers, there are 1000 numbers that you can bet on, so a fair payoff would be 1000 to 1. Giving a payoff of only 600 to 1 lets the people running the game keep 40% of the money bet, which is around right — if you keep too much, the gamblers might realize that they are being had, and stop betting.

Further, if Miss Pearl bet $1, then you can deduce that she could probably spare the dollar, and so is one of those people who "need the least" and who "always get lucky". The really poor folk would be betting only nickels or dimes, if you believe the blog entry.

Presumably Miss Pearl plays 651 as her numbers, so this is the second time she's won. The reason she had a spare dollar is because she hasn't yet spent all her winnings from the first time she won, hence "those that need the least always get lucky"

@PeterShor FYI, state lotteries these days pay out about 60% of the receipts.
